# How to extract folder one directory level up?

Tags: unix, terminal

I am looking for a shell command (I am on MacOS bash) that can do this job for me:

So I have a folder with this structure:

```
.
├── Erie
│   └── archive
│       ├── 001
│       ├── 002
│       ├── 003
│       └── 004
│           ├── 0041
│           ├── 0042
│           └── 0043
└── SB
    └── archive
        ├── 002
        ├── 003
        └── 004
```

Essentially I would like to get rid of the level "archive", and reorganize the folder to

```
.
├── Erie
│    ├── 001
│    ├── 002
│    ├── 003
│    └── 004
│        ├── 0041
│        ├── 0042
│        └── 0043
└── SB
    ├── 001
    ├── 002
    └── 003
```

What I have tried:

```bash
cd Erie
find . -depth 2 -type d 
# outputs:
#./archive/001
#./archive/003
#./archive/004
#./archive/002
```

Then I want to attach commands to move these directories one level up. I tried either find `-exec` or `xargs` function, but I couldn't work this out:

**Method 1:**

```
find . -depth 2 -type d | xargs mv .

# gives me an error: 
# mv: rename . to ./archive/002/.: Invalid argument

# this also generates a weird folder structure:
.
└── archive
    └── 002
        ├── 001
        ├── 003
        └── 004
            ├── 0041
            ├── 0042
            └── 0043
```

**Method 2:**

```
find . -depth 2 -type d -exec mv {} . ;

# This give me an error as well:
# find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple suggestion:

```
for Dir in Erie SB
do find "$Dir"/archive -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -v '{}' "$Dir" ';'
rmdir -v "$Dir"/archive
done
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or, without using `find`:

```
for d in Erie SB; do mv $d/archive/* $d/; rmdir $d/archive; done
```